# Vus.js v-if based on reactive data: view not reactive

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and I'm having trouble to understand the conditional rendering.

Here in my template a button I'd like to render conditionally:

```
<q-chip v-if="validationRequestSent===false" @click="initiateValidation(prop.node.id)">
 Request validation
 </q-chip>
```

validationRequestSent is a reactive data:

```
<script lang="js">

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        validationRequestSent: false
      }
    },
```

When I click on the button, I set validationRequestSent to true:

```
 async initiateValidation(id) {
        this.validationRequestSent= true;
        const validationId = await ValidationClient.initiateValidation(id)
        this.validationRequestSent= false;
        this.$router.push({name: this.determineRouteAfterInitiateValidation()});
      },
```

I was hoping that the button would then disappeared, but nothing happens.

Can someone help me understand what happens?

Comment: remove the line after `this.validationId = ....`. because you reset the reactive variable to which the condition refers. In your case `validationRequestSent` is always false. You should do the reset in another place.

Comment: Also you can just say ```<q-chip v-if="!validationRequestSent" ...```

Comment: Your code should actually work as expected...unless `ValidationClient.init...` finishes instantly...see [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-buck-25ry9?file=/src/App.vue)